# Proof that a certain domain is a valuation ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Suppose that $A$ is an integral domain such that, for every two distinct ideals $I,J\subseteq A$, either $I\subseteq J$ or $J\subseteq I$. Show that $A$ is a valuation ring in its field of fractions.

Take an element of $\operatorname{Frac} A$, that can be written as $\frac xy$ for $x,y\in A$. Since either $x\in (y)$ or $y\in (x)$, I have that, respectively, either $\frac xy\in A$ or $\frac yx\in A$. Is it correct? It seems very trivial to be an exercise from a past exam, so I'm afraid that I took for granted something that in a generic domain doesn't hold true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof seems correct. If $y\neq 0$ take any $x/y\in \operatorname{Frac}A$. W.l.o.g. assume that $(y)\subset (x)$ in particular there is some $a\in A$ s.t. $xa=y$ and thus, $x/y= \frac{x}{xa} = \frac{1}{a} = (\frac{a}{1})^{-1}$ and because $a/1\in A$ the claim follows. One tiny thing to note ist that $\in A$ here means that the element is in the image of the canonical morphism $\phi : A\to \operatorname{Frac} A, \ x\mapsto x/1$ which establishes a canonical isomorphism $A \cong \phi(A) \subset \operatorname{Frac}A$.